# Unread message count in a PHP app

Tags: php, javascript, sql, message

I am currently developing a simple PHP application where users can send messages to each other. Messages are stored in a SQL database. I'd like to put a count of unread messages in the menu on every page, so that a user can see quickly if they have new messages without checking the inbox periodically.

While this may be an easy problem to solve, I don't know what the best method would be, performance-wise :

1. **Do a plain SQL COUNT() of unread messages on every page load** (instantly notified of changes, but it may impact performance badly ?)
2. **Do the same thing, but cache the result for X minutes** (we create an annoying delay)
3. Same as 2., but **only update when we read a message or when a message is sent to us** (can use up a lot of RAM / stress the disk, since we create one persistent entry/file per user : we can't store it in $_SESSION because we need to update it when another user sends a message to us)

All my solutions are somewhat server-based, because I'm not very familiar with JS. But if a better solution exists using JavaScript, It's okay.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest 4'th:

Once new message has been sent to a user, you update counter in `memcache`. You create simple ajax application on client side sending a request every X seconds. At server side, you just check is there unread messages. At page refresh, you don't need to query the database since you get count from `memcache` extremely fast.

That's what I'd done if I had bottleneck in DB (in 90% cases, DB is the weekest part of any database-driven application).

That's what we usually do at highloaded web sites: we trying to avoid any COUNTER queries. If not, we denormalize the database to store counters right in the appropriate table as yet another column e.g. if you can not use `memcache`, you would store the unread messages counter as a column for `Users` table.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the best solution. However, it means adding yet another dependency to my application. Thank you for the answer !

Comment: Yep. It's kind of hard to maintain especially when your application is growing up, but cmon! facebook use MySQL as key-value storage and mostly rely on `memcache`. Dealing with highloads you will have to sacrifice something.

Comment: @Artefact & @Nemoden ever heard of: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Installing memcache and other stuff before you have your app running is not wise. You should first just build your app the simple way and update your app when performance issues come around.

Comment: @RJD22 I know about this expression. I read some literature. I also work on application with over 600k every day users and over 2000 hits per second. `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE` to master server would cause performance issues. Did anybody said that we are dealing with application that is not running? I think if @Artefact2 asked about this he's concerned with performance. Why would he otherwise, if everything works fine with `SELECT COUNT()` ?

Comment: @Nemoden He is still developing it. Imo it's best to get something simple running first before going to optimize. It could even be that in his case the count is the least of his worries :P

Comment: In this case - yes, I agree. Usually we should optimize if needed. BUT it does not mean that we should write not scalable software.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for option three, except I'd add [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) as solution 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Do a plain SQL COUNT() of unread
>   messages on every page load (instantly
>   notified of changes, but it may impact
>   performance badly ?)

As long as you have a decent table structure, COUNT() is a pretty fast command. I wouldn't cache this particular command. I'd instead work out the other queries to make sure you're only returning the data you need when showing them a listing. For example, if all you need is an excerpt, I'd make sure to do something like this:

```
SELECT id, author, msgdate, substring(body, 0, 50) from table where recipient = ?
```

instead of

```
SELECT * from table where recipient = ?;
```

Comment: I'm yet a bit worried about the COUNT() performance, because one message can have multiple recipients, each of them may or may not have read the message, etc. Counting unread messages actually involves an ANTI JOIN…

Answer (score 0):

Imho. It's best to let the client ping the server and send a json back with the amount of unread messages. Counting in mysql should be fast so I see no reason not to use it. Just filter the results on the chat session.

For the database part. The best way would be to store a new_message filled in your db table and default it to 1, and set that one to 0 when the message has been loaded.