# FB PHP SDK change unread message status to read and counting Unread Messages

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need some help after I could not able to find the solution for this. There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856257/unread-message-count-in-a-php-app) but no accepted answer. I am using FB PHP SDK v4.4.0 and now I am able to pull out all the conversations between other users and my page. However, I am wondering on how do I change the status of "unread" to "read". I want to pull the conversations and store them in MySQL. However, for performance-wise, I like to pull only the "unread" message instead of pulling everything. This makes the process slower due to the increasing number of conversations in the future.

Here is the part of my current code that I have that will list out all of the conversations in very sophisticated array:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $api_key, $api_secret );
$session = new FacebookSession($accessPageToken);
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/conversations'); 
$Convs = $request->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own research and reading, I could not able to find how to change the Facebook internal status from "unread" to "read". You have to manually do it in your own environment.

However one of my finding is when you use the API to send out the reply, all the "unread" message will no longer be "unread", they will become "read". Hopefully this could help somebody. Or if anybody has their other finding, you can share it here as well.

Thank you.